# Is "Please give me one day of time" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to take one day for someone. What will the correct way to write be?

1. Please give me one day of time.
2. Please give me one day at time.
3. Please give me one day time.

Through I know "Please give me one day" is sufficient to pass my message, I would like to also know its association with *time*.

Comment: Hi Joy, welcome to ELL! Unfortunately this question is not clear. All of these sentences, when fixed grammatically, can mean entirely different things. What we need you to do, then, is to edit and explain what you want to *mean*, and then we can give you a sentence with that meaning. *I want to take one day time for someone* doesn't make sense (as in, I don't know what you want to say). Possible ideas of what you might mean: 1) I want a day off of work. 2) I need one more day to complete [x] task. Without further information it's hard to know what you want. Please edit to add! Thanks :)

Comment: Joy, you need to give more context for the question. At the moment, it is not clear what exactly one day is needed for. What is the situation that one day applies to?

Answer (score 4):

You don't generally combine day and time like that in a sentence. I'm not sure I can offer you an alternative since I am not sure what message you are trying to communicate.

"Please give me one day" is usually a response to someone when you need one more day to complete something.

For example:

> Can you finish this report for me?
>
> Yes, just give me one day.

What are you looking to communicate with 'day time'?

Comment: I think he/she is trying to say 'he needs {time of} one day to complete the X', in that case what you said seems correct to me.

Comment: Yes Joe, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

If you are saying that you are asking for time to complete some task or to prepare for something, the normal way to phrase it would be, "Please give me one day."

It would be grammatically and technically accurate to say, "Please give me one day of time". But no one says that, because a day is a unit of time, and so to say "one day of time" is redundant. As opposed to what, a day of height? Well, I suppose you could imagine some context where it might be unclear without specifying "of time", like if you had just been talking about "a day of sales" meaning the amount of money the company made in one day, or something of that sort.

"One day at time" doesn't make sense. People do say, "one day at a time", as in, "I am going to deal with my problems one day at a time", meaning, I am not going to worry about the long term, but just worry about each day's problems as they come.

"One day time" doesn't make sense here. We do say "day time" to mean the part of the day that is light, as opposed to "night time". But I don't recall ever hearing it used with a number. You might say, "I like to walk in the park during the day time", meaning you want to do it when the sun is up rather than when it's dark. But people don't say, "I spent three day times working on this." I've just never heard the phrase used that way.

Answer (score 0):

By one day of time, do you mean one work day, or a 24 hour period? Saying "Please give me one day" usually means the first, while saying a "day of time" has a literal meaning of 24 hours.

> 1. Please give me one day of time [to complete this task].

This is the only sentence that is grammatically correct.

A colloquial approach would be :

> I need a day to do X.
>
> Please give me a day to work on X.
>
> I can have X done in a day.