# Is “square foot of area” correct?

Tags: phrases

In German it is quite common to say „Bitte gib mir einen Tag Zeit.“  **Literally** this is “[*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/394/232) Please give me one day of time.”, but [this is not correct in English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6010/232)! While “Please give me one bottle of/with/... milk.” seems to be correct (isn't it?) the hyper-linked question got me thinking about area/space/...:

Is “This box occupies seven square foot (0.65 square meter) of area/space/the floor/...”  correct?

“square foot/meter” is a measure for some area, therefore “of area” is as redundant as “of time” in combination with “one day”, but “meter of space” and “foot of space” seem to be quite common according to a popular search engine (which still would not make ungrammatical usage right).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I regard “This box occupies seven square feet of area” as a correct utterance, in spite of the redundancy.  A problem with “This box occupies seven square feet” is that  *occupies* often is taken to refer to the volume a box occupies, leading to a slight cognitive dissonance.  The forms “This box covers seven square feet” or  “This box has a seven-square-foot footprint” don't have that problem, and when “space” or “the floor” are used rather than “area”, the redundancy is lessened as well.

Regarding „Bitte gib mir einen Tag Zeit“, English forms such as “Please give me a day of your time” or “Please give me another day to fix this” or even “Please give me another day of time to fix this” sound natural enough, although I think it's unlikely the last would be often heard.

Comment: Whilst we don't say things like *"I need another **day of time** to finish this project"*, we certainly *do* say things like *"Please give me a few minutes [**of your time**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22minutes+of+your+time%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)"*

Comment: And there are people who will say things like "in one day's time".